# Verbally accepted an offer at a company but received another offer

Tags: job-offer, new-job, hiring-process

I applied to companies A and B four days apart.

I started interviewing at company A right away, and they had a pretty lengthy interview process. I had 4 interviews and an assessment with them, and I was supposed to have 2 more interviews, but they skipped the two other interviews to bring me onboard faster since they really wanted me.

I did verbally accept the job offer since I did not have anything else coming along, but they said it was contingent upon a background check and a drug screen. The background check has taken about a week so far, and I have not signed any type of an employment contract yet. They said today that the background check came back, but they still wanted additional information to review things (W2 transcripts) that I sent to them this morning. I do not know if they are going to be giving me an employment contract to sign anytime soon since it seems like they are digging in deep as far as the background check.

The day that I had given the verbal offer to company A, I interviewed at company B thinking that I would not get anywhere since I was a bit under-qualified for the job and the interview practice would not hurt. They really liked me after the initial HR screen and first round of interviews, gave me a technical assessment, and then I had a second round of interviews with C-Level staff and other team members. That interview went really well as well, and they gave me an offer today.

I like company B more than company A because I seemed to get along more with the team, the technology stack and industry is something I would want to work with more than company A, and the benefits and PTO package at company B is way better than company A. Company B is also paying $5K more in salary than company A.

Not sure how to let company A know that I have another offer that is better than theirs, and that I'm more than likely going to be taking it. I really don't want to burn bridges with company A since they are really nice people too, but company B's offering is really too good for me to pass up.

Is there a good way to let company A know about company B's offer without burning bridges too badly?

Comment: This happens all of the time. Just inform company A that you have received an offer from another company and have decided to pursue that opportunity. Thank them for their time and wish them the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no formal offer from company A.  Even if you did, letting them know as soon as possible is the right thing to do.  You can outline the facts:  your salary, benefits, and responsibilities are better at company B.  Please keep your opinion about company B being better than A to yourself.

If they are a reasonable company, then you will not be burning any bridges.  They should be happy for your success.  They should be looking, at themselves, to understand why you decided upon another company.

Perhaps a dysfunctional company might see this as disloyalty, but then you probably don't want to work their anyway.

Good job!

Comment: I would agree with you as well. I ended up writing an email since there were multiple HR people I was working with at company A for their onboarding process. I have not heard anything back yet, but I would be very surprised if they tried to counteroffer at this pont.

Comment: I agree. If Company A is smart they'll be able to go back to the second best candidate and offer your job to them. Best for all if you do it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 11):

You just have to be professional about it and let company A know ASAP that you won't be joining them because you had an offer elsewhere which better matches your long term goals. No need to name company B in that communication.

I'm sure a few bridges will be burned, but if you're at company B for the long term, it won't really matter.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I do plan on staying at my next job for at least the next 3-5 years, so it probably won't matter in the end. Also, this job will take my career in a totally different direction than company A. Thanks for your thoughts!